# Why can't I bind to this socket in PHP?

Tags: php, windows, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I am running an apache2 server from a windows computer using the Linux subsystem. Now I'm trying to use it as a server and listen to connections. Unfortunately it is failing when trying to bind to the socket. This is the code:

```
$host = '0.0.0.0';
$port = 1433;

set_time_limit(0);

if(!$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) {
    die("Couldn't create socket! reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n");  
}

if(!$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port)) {
    die("Couldn't bind socket! reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n");    
}
```

The error code just states that permission is denied, however I have allowed this specific port through my firewall. I am quite new to the whole php server-side thing, so I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Change the host to 127.0.0.1, which is localhost or home. The  0.0. 0.0 address is a non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or non-applicable target

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately this resulted in the same error:

Couldn't bind to socket! reason: Permission denied

Comment: Where are you setting `$socket`?

Comment: In that if statement. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, that could be the problem. You should set `$socket` then test `if(!$socket) {...`

Comment: Doesn't look like it fixed it either D: at least my code is a lot more readable with $result and $socket pulled out of those statements

Comment: Without being able to look more closely at your system this may be hard to solve, especially if it is a permissions issue.